# Make a method be able to take two different types as parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm working on a project and I'm getting kind of tired of writing .sets constantly, so I was going to make a few methods to abbreviate the code and make it quicker. I'm using JButtons, JLabels, and JTextFields, is there a way I could write a method to have the ability to .setInvisible(false); on any of these? Or do I have to have separate methods for each type. Thank you!

Example:

```
public void siv((JButton || JLabel || JTextField) input) {
input.setVisible(false);
}
```

***Edit:
Just to be clear I'm trying to see if there is a way Java can understand to take the one entered as opposed to needing all three. I'm trying to find a way to do this without doing what I've added below:

```
private void siv(JButton input, JTextField input2, JLabel input3) {
    input.setVisible(false);
    input2.setVisible(false);
    input3.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Only by means of interfaces and/or inheritance. With the given syntax, however, it is not possible.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: The way I understand the question, it seems you need to specify the method as `private void siv(JComponent input)` since both `JButton`, `JTextField` and `JLabel` inherit the `setVisible` method from that class

Answer (score 6):

`JButton`, `JTextField`, and `JLabel` inherit from `JComponent` which has the method `setVisible`, so you can have a method that takes an array of `JComponent` and sets their visibilities.

```
 public void setVisibility(boolean visibility, JComponent... components) {
   for(JComponent component: components){ 
     component.setVisible(visibility);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great!

Comment: Building on @sleiman-jneidi's answer, if you wanted to have a method that accepts _only_ the three classes you mentioned, you would have to overload that method - essentially write _three_ methods with same name, each one taking a parameter of the right type. You can then write the code itself in triplicate or delegate to a private method that takes a JComponent.